# The Android emulator began to slow down

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

For no reason my emulator began to slow down. Each action occurs with a delay. And when the emulator starts, this message is displayed.

> Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver
>   version. As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer. Please
>   check with your manafacturer to see if there is an updated driver
>   available.

I tried to change the driver of the video card and create a new emulator, this does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio, Suddenly got GPU Driver Issue when running emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121828/android-studio-suddenly-got-gpu-driver-issue-when-running-emulator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for me:

1. Open your **SDK Emulator** folder (e.g. C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator )
2. Open **Command Line** window here
3. Enter the: `emulator -list-avds` (to see a list of available emulators)
4. Enter the: `emulator -avd {name_of_emulator} -gpu host` (for the forced-choice hardware gpu)
5. You will see a warning again, but just ignore it.
6. The emulator will no longer slow down

Comment: No. But this bug was gone after last updates of android emulator. You should check updates in sdk manager.

Comment: same issue occurred after updating android emulator.

Answer (score 2):

For my solution I did

1. In your emulator, click more
2. Select setting
3. in advance tab
4. change the OpenGL ES renderer to 'Desktop Native OpenGL