# GPU Driver Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

[image: GPU Driver Issue]

Recently I am getting this error while running the emulator.I deleted and then re-created a new AVD but it didn't work as well and still showing me the same error. It's happening over all the projects and I have also noticed a performance drop while running the AVD.

Comment: Have you checked if there is an update to your GPU driver?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, I have checked for driver updates & everything is updated but I don't see any recent updates for display drivers. That's strange & still this issue is there.

Comment: I've also faced this kind of problem, each time opening a google map activity it will crash. But when using adb device there is no problem

Comment: Friend the solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121828/android-studio-suddenly-got-gpu-driver-issue-when-running-emulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio, Suddenly got GPU Driver Issue when running emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121828/android-studio-suddenly-got-gpu-driver-issue-when-running-emulator)

Answer (score -1):

Open Device Manger and delete Intel HD Graphics (check "Delete drivers" in popup). When ask reboot-ask No. Now U can use Emulator ).

P.S. This action maybe need after every reboot. Or U can try disable automatic driver updates. I think this maybe helpfull - http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/stop-automatic-driver-updates-windows-10 (not test this, because rarely
reboot PC)