# Emulator causes Windows Blue Screen DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, blue-screen-of-death

Recently when I launch the android emulator after some minutes it makes the CPU 100%, the fan of laptop starts spinning very high, the PC become unusable for some seconds and after all the `Blue Screen` pops out with the message:

> DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

```
Windows 10 x64
CPU Core i5 7300HQ
GPU NVidia GTX1050
RAM 12GB
SSD NVMe 250GB
Android Studio 3.0.1
Emulator API 25, 26, 27
```

EDIT 1: Even after Android Emulator 27.0.2 update the problem exists.

Comment: I haven’t been able to solve this problem yet. I'm disabling the NVidia from Device manager and working with the internal GPU.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem after updating to Android Studio 3.0. I have solved this problem by reinstalling the NDIVIA driver from the asus home page (not installed by window update). I use an laptop Asus/GTX1050/i7/16GB/250GB SSD.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Asus GL553 VD, GTX 1050/i7/16GB/128GB SSD
And the emulator is making my life a living hell, sometimes it crashed for TDR_VIDEO_FAILURE and other times for DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE.

i did find in another answer that you should run the emulator with this command

```
emulator -avd avd_name -gpu mode
```

[link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121828/android-studio-suddenly-got-gpu-driver-issue-when-running-emulator)

Comment: I recently disabling the GTX 1050 Graphic adapter through `Device Manager` and it works smoothly.