# Android Studio Emulator running results in Windows 10 blue screen of death

Tags: android, android-studio

I am experiencing BSOD issues after running the emulator in AS for a few minutes, I have tested multiple Android versions and I always get the same.

Also tried on different AS versions.

I have tried searching for the same error code from other Stackoverflow issues that recommended this place: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=emulator%20bsod but seems this issue is not reported.

Also I tried creating a new one, but it seems I do not have permissions on Google's issue tracker, hence why I post here.

Here the screen I get:

The error I get on BSOD is DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

For reference if that is useful I am using AS version:

- Android Studio 4.0.1
- Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020
- Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10 10.0
- GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
- Memory: 1237M
- Cores: 8
- Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
- Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.google.services.firebase

I can provide any other logs necessary.

Comment: You should include CPU (Intel/AMD), how much RAM, free disk space, general PC info, version of Windows as well as what if any other VMs are use in your machine. Also state what GPU is being used and if you've tried the [steps in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55119178/295004)

Comment: Thank you @MorrisonChang that did the trick! Using the command line with the GPU parameter fixed it.