# Running Android Emulator from Android Studio terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to learn about creating Android Apps, using Android Studio 3.1.2

I want to run this app on an emulator, so I created an Emulator called it **OREO Emulator**.

But whenever I press the run button, I get a GPU error, and went to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121828/android-studio-suddenly-got-gpu-driver-issue-when-running-emulator), one of the solutions is to use Android Studio Terminal, go to the address where the emulator is located, and type in the following command

`emulator -avd [avd_name] -gpu [mode]`

But unfortunately that address doesn't exist in my laptop, so what I should type in the terminal is:

`emulator -avd OREO_Emulator -gpu host`
but when I do that it says that emulator is not recognised as a command.

Can anyone help me with that.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first must open the Path of the folder:

> cd C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

Where userName is your user in case of Windows

After If you want you could add the PATH to the envoriment variables in order to dont need to open the folder path every time that you need it.