# Issue related to graphics driver while running an application using the emulator

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android application development. while running android application with the emulator, driver version is missing and getting the error mentioned in the image.
Could someone help me understand this error?

```
Your GPU driver information:

GPU #1
Make: 8086
Model: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
Device ID: 0166

Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version. As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.
```

[click on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJDsJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating your drivers as it seems to be GPU issue

or you can try using hardware graphics (by preventing emulator to the device )
refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45124147/7579041) answer