# Changing renderer for the Android emulator has no effect

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When starting the emulator from Android Studio AVD manager I suddenly get this message:

```
Your GPU driver information:

GPU #1
  Make: 8086
  Model: 0166
  Device ID: 0166
GPU #2
  Make: 8086
  Model: 0166
  Device ID: 0166

Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.  As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer.  Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.
```

I don't know why it suddenly started appearing. It didn't appear yesterday, and I haven't updated any drivers or the emulator or Android Studio.

So, I change `OpenGL ES renderer` to `Desktop native OpenGL` in the emulator settings according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574323/220820). I don't have the `ANGLE` option so I figured that's the closest I could get.

When I quit and relaunch the emulator I get the same error message.

Editing the device in AVD manager doesn't work either -- I cannot click Finish after editing the existing device:

[image: Editing AVD]

It says `You must select a Device to create an AVD` which I don't understand, since I'm editing an existing AVD that I can obviously already run.

How do I stop the emulator from using the compatibility renderer without having to launch the emulator from terminal every time?

*macOS 10.14.1*

*Android Studio 3.2.1*

*Emulator 27.3.10-4969155*

Comment: Try selecting a device by clicking the "Change.." button next to "No Hardware Profile Selected".