# my android emulator is not working, please assist?

Tags: android, emulation

I have been having problems loading my android emulator. I thought it was just slow to load but i have waited sometimes up to 15 minutes and still does not load. It keep telling me this message before I start it:

Your GPU driver information:

```
GPU #1
  Make: 8086
  Model: 0166
  Device ID: 0166
```

Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.  As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer.  Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.

when i run flutter run on my terminal, it says this: 
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.

I am currently running the android studio and emulator on macOS mojave.

Really appreciate your help on what to do.

Comment: Please share your system hardware configuration, OS, and software versions.

Comment: ✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 36.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)            




iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001

Comment: What is your GPU, and its driver version?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 4000:

  Chipset Model: Intel HD Graphics 4000
  Type: GPU
  Bus: Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
  Vendor: Intel
  Device ID: 0x0166
  Revision ID: 0x0009
  Metal: Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily1 v4
  Displays:
Colour LCD:
  Display Type: LCD
  Resolution: 1280 x 800
  UI Looks like: 1280 x 800
  Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Colour (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror: Off
  Online: Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness: No

Comment: What is your OS and its version?

Comment: macOS MOJAVE version: 10.14.5 (18F132)

Comment: It's your GPU issue brother, Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574323/10270165) carefully. Check the Update 2# into the answer

Comment: thanks. will try it out soon =)

Comment: I am getting identical issue

Answer (score 0):

try this 2 solutions ,one of them may help you !

**Solution 1**

try updating your emulator and related files in Android Studio. I believe you can do this by clicking "Help" -> "Check for updates" in Android Studio and then letting it install all updates.

You may need to check for updates from the "Beta channel" (it is usually "Stable channel" by default). You can do this by clicking File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates and making sure to check the "Automatically check for updates" box, as well as "Beta channel" in the drop-down list.

After this is all completed, try restarting Android Studio and then do a fresh clean/rebuild of the project.

**Solution 2**

- Delete all AVD's that you currently have.
- Go to Preferences >> Android SDK >> SDK Tools
- Uninstall Android Emulator
- Restart Android Studio.
- Re-install Android Emulator from the same place.
- Create a new emulator !

Comment: i have tried this , but nothing seem to work. when i run flutter run in terminal : it says this: Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.